# is it possible to (mis-) use string class in ruby to get all strings I18n translated? (theoretical issue)

Tags: ruby

This is a question for theory and better understanding ruby, not a question for real life. So please don't comment like "never do that" or similar.

Imagine, I do not want to use `I18n.t "token"`, I want to use: `"token".t` instead. This is easy with:

```
class String
    def t
        I18n.t self
    end
end
```

Imagine, I use strict `symbols` for logic and `strings` for text, and want to get every `string`  through I18n logic.

Is that possible without the `.t`?  So that `a="john".t #a gets 'johann' in German` is the same as just `a="john"`

It would be something like *change the value while object creation* I think.

Again, this is a question for theory and understanding ruby, not a question for I18n or real life.

Comment: So you want to replace the string literal constructor?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think thats the direction (BTW: mu -  are answering all my questions? ;-))

Comment: @muistooshort: Something different: "MU is too short"? Like "Make MI from MU" in the book "goedl, escher, bach (Douglas R. Hofstadter)"?

Comment: Actually `µ` from [Measure Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29) but the Zen meaning works just as well.

Comment: If translation really is the goal then I'd switch to gettext and say `_('Pancakes')` instead of all that nasty `I18n.t 'some-confusing-code'` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1893190) you can't redefine initialization of string literals, but nevertheless you can redefine `String` initialization using [alias or alias_method](http://wikimatze.de/method-alias-in-ruby/) and write something like:

```
 class String
   alias_method :old_init, :initialize
   def initialize(str)
     old_init(str)
     puts self
   end
end
a = String.new("x")
```

Comment: according to the 'thread' it looks like I am touching a hornets nest ... It will take a while for me to get that thread into my mind ...

Comment: Well the discussion was over back in 2011. I don't think they will add this feature if they have not done it before.

Comment: So with Ruby its like 'animal Farm': everything is an object; all objects are equal but literals are more equal; and I dont want it as a feature! I think changeing the Literal constructor would be an evil sin. My question was only theoretical.